i have problem with duplicated image download with pixijs
i preloading the images in root of the project
const planeImages = [
  '/canvas/plane/1.png',
  '/canvas/plane/2.png',
  '/canvas/plane/3.png',
  '/canvas/plane/4.png',
  '/canvas/plane/5.png',
];

const promise = (src) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = resolve;
  });

const preloadImages = async (images) => {
  const imagePromises = images.map((src) => promise(src));
  await Promise.all(imagePromises);
};

and want to use in react-pixi
import plane1 from '/canvas/plane/1.png';
import plane2 from '/canvas/plane/2.png';
import plane3 from '/canvas/plane/3.png';
import plane4 from '/canvas/plane/4.png';
import plane5 from '/canvas/plane/5.png';
const images = [plane1, plane2, plane3, plane4, plane5];

// const images = [
//   '/canvas/plane/1.png',
//   '/canvas/plane/2.png',
//   '/canvas/plane/3.png',
//   '/canvas/plane/4.png',
//   '/canvas/plane/5.png',
// ];


<AnimatedSprite isPlaying images={images} animationSpeed={0.4} anchor={{ x: 0.1, y: 0.9 }} />

I tried both way but still duplicate downloands
i want to make one preload and use in pixijs this preloaded images

A 304 Not Modified response isn't exactly a "duplicate download" - the client has made a conditional GET request to the server, to see if it needs to download the resource again, and the server responded, that there is no need for that, and the client should use its already cached version. If you want to avoid the conditional request, then you probably need to serve your images with different caching instructions to begin with.
